# Making a model unique for each user?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably easy but I don't know the term for it...

I have a user model on a website I am creating that displays videos.

The user can mark a video as "watched". It has a default state of false.

I want to make it so if User A marks a video as "watched" (making the value "true) that when User B looks at the video it shows up as false.

I.E. each video is "unique" for every user.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should create another model so that you can store who has watched which video individually.

For an example, you've already created `User` and `Video`. You need to create another model that will store watched video by certain users. For an example, we'll name it as `WatchedVideo`. It will have `user_id` and `video_id` as its attributes.

Update your model to set the `has_many through` association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, through: :watched_videos
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :watched_videos
end

class WatchedVideo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video
end
```

So, the next time a user has watched a video, just add a record in the `WatchedVideo`. Examples:

```
# Create the viewing record
# Create a controller and define an action that will do something like this
# POST using AJAX or whatever method suitable for you
w = User.find(1).watched_videos.build
# w = current_user.watched_videos.build
w.video_id = params[:video_id]
w.save

# Check if the user has watched the video 
# so that you can set wheter the User A/B has viewed it or not
WatchedVideo.where(user_id: 1, video_id: 2)
User.find(1).watched_videos.where(2)
```

So, if any of those commands return not nil, then, the particular user (id=1) has watched the video.

You also need to do unique validation so that the user won't be able to mark watched more than 1 time.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video

  validates :video_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

Reference:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

Comment: There is a typo in the first block of code. (two User classes)

Comment: lol, thanks, forgot to reedit after pasting the previous code

Comment: Thank you so much for this! How do I go about adding a WatchedVideo entry? Let's say User1 checked "watched" on video1. How do I put this into the DB? Thanks!!

Comment: Generate a migration to add it to the database.